# How to implement the Laravel Socialite package on registration and login api with laravel passport

Tags: laravel, google-oauth, laravel-passport, laravel-socialite

I was trying to learn how to do the auth with the socialite. I have never used this package before this moment. So totally new here on the package. The real question is how to get the Google 0Auth details.

```
'google' => [
    'client_id'     => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect'      => env('GOOGLE_REDIRECT'),
],
```

for API, I am using the passport package for laravel. so whatever call I will be making is to the passport API. So how to Implement the with the socialite package?

Comment: https://medium.com/@Alabuja/social-login-in-laravel-with-socialite-90dbf14ee0ab